# Access static methods and fields with class type returned by dlsym

Tags: dynamic-loading, dlsym

Can we access static methods and fields with class type returned by dlsym?

Ex:

```
MyClass* pMyClass= (MyClass*)dlsym(phandle, "MyClass");
pMyClass->staticFunction();
pMyClass->staticField=0;
```

;

Comment: did you try anything? :)

Comment: Yes, got linker error :(

Comment: this gives little information for help.   pls provide the complete code and what you exactly got.

Comment: My code looks very similar to the example provided in the question.
I tried to access staticFunction but got standard symbol not found error